# Comparing String Dates Pulled From MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, database

I have a relation in a MySQL database which stores dates in the form of varchar along with other attributes. It looks something like:

Answers
answerId
answer
questionId
date

I have a web application where the user will select a 'from' and 'to' date and I will need to pull the relevant answers between the ranges provided. So my question is how would I implement a php file which queried the database correctly pulling out the answers between the dates provided..

Comment: What is your reason for storing dates as VARCHAR instead of one of the proper date types, such as DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: The dates are stored in a varchar? What format is the date? Is it still in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: Someone else built the schema and now it is populated with data..that aside, the dates are stored as dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

If you date is in `YY-mm-dd` (From greatest to lowest, with leading zeros) you can compare it as string(lexicographically)

But You should use proper datatype for date (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for it:

You can convert a date (that is already stored in your MySQL db) to [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and compare it like any number.

e.g

```
$date1 =  strtotime("2010-11-12");  
$date2 =  strtotime("2010-11-14");
```

and just compare `$date1` and `$date2`.

here is the link that will help you
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

As @RiaD wrote you use proper date types. But if you can't change type you should 
convert Varchar string to DATETIME using **STR_TO_DATE**.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

So you query will be looked like

```
Select * from table
where STR_TO_DATE(field_name, 'YOUR_DATE_FORMAT') between start_date and end_date;
```